# Translate all innerText in document html with google translate api

Tags: javascript, google-translate

i am making a request to this url to translate text from english to spanish

URL: https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=es&dt=t&q=Hello

and efectivelly i´m getting translated text to spanish, so, now i want to get dinamically all innerText in body document and then put again translated text, how can i do this?

In simple words, I want to dynamically translate the website with a button click.

This is my example code to start:

```js
let textToBeTranslate =["hello","thanks","for","help me"]
var url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=es&dt=t&q="+textToBeTranslate;

  fetch(url)
    .then(data => data.json()).then(data => {
      //Text translated to spanish
      var textTranslated = data[0][0][0].split(", ");
      console.log(textTranslated)
         //output: ["hola gracias por ayudarme"]
         //Now i want to dinamically put translated text in body tag again          
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    });
```

Comment: So you want to translate all text in an HTML document? Can you provide a simplified example of what this document might look like? Thanks.

Comment: You will have to account for the document structure i.e. if it has <h>, <p> and other elements that are designed to hold text. Basically you will have to loop through these elements and update them one by one with the translated text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const translateElement = async element => {
    const
        elementNode = element.childNodes[0],
        sourceText = elementNode && elementNode.nodeValue;

    if (sourceText) 
        try {
            const
                url = 'https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=es&dt=t&q=' + sourceText,
                resultJson = await fetch(url),
                result = await resultJson.json(),
                translatedText = result[0][0][0].split(', ');

            elementNode.nodeValue = translatedText;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}
```

For a single element - Just call it, like this:

```
(async () => await translateElement(document.body))();
```

For all elements in the DOM - You will need to recursively go over all elements starting from the desired parent tag (`body`, in your case), and call the above function for each element, like this:

```
(async () => {
    const
        parent = 'body',
        selector = `${parent}, ${parent} *`,
        elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)],
        promises = elements.map(translateElement);

    await Promise.all(promises);
})();
```

Remarks:

1. I used `childNodes[0].nodeValue` instead of `innerHtml` or
   `innerText` to keep the child elements.
2. Note that go over the entire DOM is not recommended and can lead to problems like changing `script` and `style` tags.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I already tested your script and it works, but it is not ideal since it sends a request for each node and google blocks the ip for making many simultaneous requests, you have another way to send all the texts to translate in a single request?

Comment: I acepted this answer because the script works, but we have to use a translate api with unlimited request, thanks @nave Sade

Comment: Hi, I think you have a problem here.
First of all - it's not best practice to send a single request for the entire text. It is much slower than sending small requests in parallel.
Second - even if you want to make a Get request for all text together, don't forget that Get requests are limited in characters (4096 sometimes, depending on platform nor browser). If it's a lot of text, it might fail because of it.
And finally - have you checked that Google doesn't block large text translation requests for free users as well? Why not buy a license..?